# Microsoft Solver Foundation SAT CNF

Tags: c#, solver, cnf

I am trying to use Microsoft Solver Foundation SatSolver to solve a simple CNF problem through Visual Studio (C# or VB).
Can anyone post a simple example explaining how this can be done?

Here is a short example:

```
        ConstraintSystem s1 = ConstraintSystem.CreateSolver();

        CspTerm t1 = s1.CreateBoolean("v1");
        CspTerm t2 = s1.CreateBoolean("v2");
        CspTerm t3 = s1.CreateBoolean("v3");
        CspTerm t4 = s1.CreateBoolean("v4");

        CspTerm tOr12 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t1), s1.Neg(t2));
        CspTerm tOr13 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t1), s1.Neg(t3));
        CspTerm tOr14 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t1), s1.Neg(t4));

        CspTerm tOr23 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t2), s1.Neg(t3));
        CspTerm tOr24 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t2), s1.Neg(t4));

        CspTerm tOr34 = s1.Or(s1.Neg(t3), s1.Neg(t4));

        CspTerm tOr = s1.Or(t1, t2, t3, t4);

        s1.AddConstraints(tOr12);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr13);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr14);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr23);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr24);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr34);
        s1.AddConstraints(tOr);

        ConstraintSolverSolution solution1 = s1.Solve();
        Console.WriteLine(solution1[t1]);
        Console.WriteLine(solution1[t2]);
        Console.WriteLine(solution1[t3]);
        Console.WriteLine(solution1[t4]);
```

The result should have only one variable with a value of 1, and the rest should have 0, but the solution is 1,1,1,0.

Thanks
Guy

Comment: The VS compiler does this automatically for you. If something will never be true, it will tell you...

Comment: Can you provide a small example?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WjAF1.jpg

Comment: I'm afraid you did not get my problem. I am not looking for a way to detect which if statements will or will not be executed in my code. I need to solve a SAT problem, defined as a CNF.

Comment: I suggest you use MiniSat or picosat instead of using this Microsoft solver. They are both easier to use and have a vibrant community to support you (and have FAQs, examples, etc. on the web)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `s1.Not(t1)` instead of `s1.Neg(t1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static SatSolver.Solve function in Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers namespace instead:

```
SatSolverParams parameters = new SatSolverParams();//default
int limVar = 5; // highest literal + 1
//add terms that are used in your code
Literal[][] clauses = new Literal[][]
{
    //Literal is represented as an int value with boolean Sense
    new Literal[] { new Literal(1, false), new Literal(2, false) },   // Clause 1: !1 or !2
    new Literal[] { new Literal(1, false), new Literal(3, false) },   // Clause 2: !1 or !3
    new Literal[] { new Literal(1, false), new Literal(4, false) },   // Clause 3: !1 or !4
    new Literal[] { new Literal(2, false), new Literal(3, false) },   // Clause 4: !2 or !3
    new Literal[] { new Literal(2, false), new Literal(4, false) },   // Clause 5: !2 or !4
    new Literal[] { new Literal(3, false), new Literal(4, false) },   // Clause 6: !3 or !4
    new Literal[] { new Literal(1, true), new Literal(2, true), new Literal(3, true), new Literal(4, true) } // Clause 7: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4
};

IEnumerable<SatSolution> solutions = SatSolver.Solve(parameters, limVar, clauses);

foreach (SatSolution solution in solutions)
{
    bool[] evaluation = new bool[4];//boolean values of individual literals
    IEnumerable<Literal> lits = solution.Literals;
    foreach (Literal lit in lits)
    {
        //lit.Var is the int value that represents the literal
        //lit.Sense is either true or false, literal or his negation
        evaluation[lit.Var - 1] = lit.Sense;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Solution found: 1 = {evaluation[0]}, 2 = {evaluation[1]}, 3 = {evaluation[2]}, 4 = {evaluation[3]}");
}
```

There are exactly 4 solutions. Each has 1 positive literal and the rest are negative. Don't forget 'using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers;'.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?